# Pass button Selected state to another view Controller

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

i have Two View Controllers. 1st controller have 1 button. i use

```
 button.selected = YES;
```

i'm using If statement to do some custom functions if the button is selected state.

```
  -(IBAction)play:(id)sender;
    {
     if (button.selected)
        {
            custom code
        }
     }
```

when i use this button in same view controller with play button it works. but i want to move the button to another view controller. but it's not working.

question is how to pass button select value to the other view controller?

Comment: Try this out.  http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/54859-sharing-data-between-view-controllers-and-other-objects-link-fixed.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you're trying to achieve. Do you just dragged a button from one interface builder window to another and wonder why that button doesn't trigger 'play:' in VC 2 or do you want to let a second view controller know about the state of a button that is a subview of view controller one?

1) If you just dragged the button from one IB window to another check the connections again. That's like the most usual problem here.

2) If you just wanna let VC 2 know about the state of the button that's currenty on VC 1 one way would be adding a BOOL to VC 2 that represents that button's state. Whenever the button get's triggered it is responsible for updating that BOOL.

Comment: Hi thanks for help.. i want is number 2.. im new to Xcode. so can u show me some sample. how to do it.

Comment: It really isn't that hard. I assume you just wanna get the solution the easy way and don't care for clean code. So go to the .h file of VC 2 and set up a property like this.

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL buttonSelected;

Then whenever the play: method gets called you simply update that BOOL with the buttons state. There are plenty ways to get that state. Look up the specific type of button in the documentation and you'll easily find one.

Comment: about which part exactly?

Comment: how im going to update the Bool when button on selected state.

Comment: You update the bool whenever the state of the button changes (and maybe one time after initialization). So the bool always shows the state of the button.